# Error converting to string, export to excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to print the result of a query in an excel, I have done all the previous steps for this process, but I have this error.

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

These are my two methods.

```php
public function reportes(Request $request)
{ 
    $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);
    $conteo = DB::table('usuarios')
        ->join('users', 'usuarios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id', DB::raw('count(nombre) as nombre'))
        ->groupBy(['usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id'])
        ->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')
        ->get();

    return view('usuario.reportes',compact('conteo'));
}

public function excel()
{             
    Excel::create('LaravelExcel', function($excel) {
        $excel->sheet('Excelsheet', function($sheet) {
            $conteo = DB::table('usuarios')
                ->join('users', 'usuarios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->select('usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id', DB::raw('count(nombre) as nombre'))
                ->groupBy(['usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id'])
                ->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')
                ->get();

            $sheet->fromArray($conteo);
            $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
        });
    })->export('xls');
}
```

How can I fix this problem if I'm doing it with the query builder?

Comment: The query builder in your `excel` method will return a collection of objects, if you add `->toArray()` it should work:  `$sheet->fromArray($conteo->toArray());`

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work that way, I need to solve it with this line after the consultation.

$ count = json_decode (json_encode ($ count), true);

Thanks for your help.